# cookie string and inserting info into text boxes

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have about 88 input boxes that I would like to have cookies repopulate onload. I have looked everywhere and cant find anything that works. I cant set one value per cookie because I have too many input boxes. All the data is less than 4000bytes. I want to break up the input values to about 20 values per cookie. So far this is all I have which isnt much. I think I need another piece of code to save the cookie string and another one to break up the cookie string and repopulate the input boxes (document.formname.inputname.value). Can someone tell me what I need here? A working piece of code would probably be best that I can just add all the document.formname.inputname.values since I dont really understand the cookie functions. I dont need the erasecookie function. Thanks.

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
} else {
    var expires = "";
}
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=",
    ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
var c = ca[i];
while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
    c = c.substring(1, c.length);
}
if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {
    return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
}
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: This is not really something that should be done with a cookie IMO. I assume there is no api backend to save this data to and to retrieve it again and you want to do this locally? Take a look at local storage maybe... http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From what I see not all browsers support local storage. I agree a cookie is probably not the ideal thing to use, but I know its been done before and works fine and thats what I want to use. I just dont know how to input and extract the data from the cookie string. Any help on the above?